# Standard file header/template like Spyder in MATLAB?

Tags: python, matlab, spyder

I like the way Spyder generates a standard header with date/user etc. like below. Is there a way to do it in MATLAB using the environment variables? I know a way to copy a template file every time, but I want to get something like below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri May 28 18:09:12 2021

@author: Rick
"""
```

Comment: [This](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/354093-generate-custom-new-script-function-template) may be what you want